# how to fabricate an aluminum square mesh?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I am working with a Physical Vapoor deposition (PVD) machine. I have 3*3cm Transistor Samples that I need to attach to the Sample holder of the PVD. I want to fabricate a "mesh" that will hold my sample holder.

The sample holder is a metal plate with holes for screws. The structure needs to be made of metal.

Below is a picture I drew in pain of what I have in mind, with the screw holes in the corners.

[image]

It doesn't seem to be that hard but I have no idea how to start or where to look. How do I go about doing this? are there companies that can do this ?

Comment: Flat metal strip comes to mind, but risks being clunky compared to your picture : even with 0.5cm wide strip...

Comment: Are they easy to assemble toghether? it has to be flat to not put more pressure on one sample than the other, but the width of each side can be 0.5 cm or larger.

Comment: Yes, cut to length, measure and drill holes, assemble, nuts & bolts or holes of two sizes with self-tapping screws or tap holes for threaded screws

Comment: Won’t be rigid though - you would have to improve your design... bracing etc

Comment: the samples  are 3*3cm *1mm thick corning glass, so don't weigh anything. So there shouldn't need any extra rigidity. however I would prefer if the structure wasn't bolted together but all one surface. maybe soldered ?

Comment: Sort all the information into your question - a long stream of comment with nuggets of info in is not helpful.

Comment: The neat way to make something like this in aluminium is as an extrusion. Your part looks a bit small to find as an off the shelf item but there are companies that make customized extrusions. That would be more suitable for a bulk order (e.g. buy a few meters of extrusion and slice it into a few hundred sample holders) than just one.

Comment: If it "has to be metal", does it have to be aluminium? Other materials are easier to braze or solder if you have to fabricate this yourself.

Comment: it doesn't have to be aluminium,  it just needs to be resistant to temperature of about 300 degrees. what do you suggest for soldering ?